# Base64 value of an empty canvas

Tags: base64

Am using the [Signature Pad](https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad) script to request a signature in some cases on a form:

```
<div id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad">
    <div class="signature-pad--body">
      <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenSignature" id="hiddenSignature" />
```

When I submit the form, I am doing this:

```
var dataURL = signaturePad.toDataURL();
$("#hiddenSignature").val(signaturePad.toDataURL("image/png").replace("data:image/png;base64,", ""));
```

And then on the server side, I am requesting the value of that field `hiddenSignature`. When there is no actual signature on the canvas, I am getting the following 'value'.

*Shouldn't the value of this field be empty for an empty canvas?*

I have confirmed via https://base64.guru/converter/decode/image that this value does convfert to an empty canvas.

```
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
```

Comment: An empty canvas is still some kind of canvas, as opposed to being no kind of thing at all.

Comment: @ScottHunter - i hear what you are saying. Its just odd, because in another application of mine, the `hiddenSignature` value I get when requesting is indeed empty ( = "") for an empty canvas.

Comment: If you want to know why 2 different pieces of code produce different results, you'd need to a) show both pieces of code and b) ask that question.